# There can be only one auto column error when giving AUTO_INCREMENT value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using phpMyAdmin while trying to create a table.

The definition is as follows

```
  CREATE TABLE `koment` (
 `movieID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`movieID`,`userID`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to have id as an auto increment variable but it seems that I can't make it thus even though it is a primary key(I needed the `id` attribute because a user can write many comments on the same movie). So I don't understand why I still get this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather advise you to have clear `PRIMARY KEY` which is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `UNIQUE KEY` like in your example:

```
CREATE TABLE `koment` (
 `movieID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY (`movieID`,`userID`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
  CREATE TABLE `koment` (
 `movieID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`movieID`,`userID`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although that wasn't really what I was trying to achieve

Comment: @Bendemann Sorry i didn see "id" . :) happy that u got solution.